How to refresh redirected page from client component in Next JS > 13
I have client component that is called in an page. There is a button on that component and click on button, it makes POST request then redirect an page. For this purpose, I used useRouter() from next/navigation. Everything is okay but I need refreshing redirected page because, the latest reponse isn't fetched.
Is there any solution? Thank you.
/home page.tsx
import { getA } from "@/action";
import React from "react";

export default function A() {
  // this func make fetch request
  const response = getA();
  return (
    <section>
      <div className="container">
        <ComponentX elements={response} />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

ComponentX.tsx
"use client";
import { Button } from "@nextui-org/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { saveX } from "@/action";

export default function ComponentX() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const create = () => {
    // this makes POST request
    saveX(req);
    router.push("/abc");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={create}>Create</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

/abc page.tsx
import { getX } from "@/action";
import React from "react";

export default function ABC() {
  // this func make fetch request
  const response = getX();
  return (
    <section>
      <div className="container">
        <ComponentY elements={response} />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

When click on Create Button, save operation done and redirect /abc page But, I need refreshing abc page, it is not.
Next Js version : 13.4.19
UPDATE
One of possible solution: Call prefetch() function.
const create = () => {
  // this makes POST request
  saveX(req);
  router.prefetch("/abc");
  router.push("/abc");
}; 


Prease share /abc page component. I think that page likely misses something.

Is that important sharing this page? This page refetch data related to saveX operations. I add this page.

It is most likely related to cache revalidation problem and there are several layers of cache.

First, page /123 is a Server Component and all Server Components cache their fetch calls by default. So getX() will get the same result if calling fetch the same URL and parameters. You can force Next.js to revalidate specific cache applying a tag name for it:
function getX(){
   ...
   const res = fetch(url, {next: {tags: ['x'] } });
   ...
};

And then calling revalidateTag from a function modifying data:
function saveX(req) {
   ...
   revalidateTag('x');
};

This way next render of route for page /123 will have new data present.
Second, there is a client side React Router Cache, which just memorize navigated and prefetched routes. It stores cache time based, usually 30 seconds and you can force revalidate it with a server action with revalidateTag or calling router.refresh().
Next's caching system is complex, you can check out the documentation page for more details.

Your abc component is likely dynamic rendered, but still caching fetched data. This means Data cache layer works for your app.
Please implement one of
the opting out methods.
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

import { getX } from "@/action";
import React from "react";
    
export default function ABC() {
   // this func make fetch request
   const response= getX();
   return (
      <section>
          <div className='container'>
             <ComponentY elements={response}/>
          </div>
      </section>  
   );
}


Yes, it is worked and your solution is one of the possible solution. Thank you.
